# Caption formatting does not work with bidi

Tags: captions, longtable, bidi

I am using the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to format figure and table captions. However, this breaks for [longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) tables when the package [bidi](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bidi) is loaded.

Here is a minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[xetex,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelfont=bf,font={small,rm},labelsep=quad]{caption}
\usepackage{bidi}

\title{A Test}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is a paragraph.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Image_1.jpg}
\caption{An image}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A simple table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
A cell & and another one \\
and a third & and a fourth \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{A long table}\\
\toprule
A cell & and another one \\
and a third & and a fourth \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: rendered PDF output]

The captions formatting works for regular table and figure captions, and it also works for longtable as long as the bidi package is not loaded.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I just took a short look into `bidi` and had already screamed out loud. It overwrites `longtable` code, too, so what should I (as maintainer of the `caption` package) do about it? Overwrite it again (\AtBeginDocument) if `bidi` is loaded? Furthermore it uses internal code of the `caption` package which will change in the near future. Its author does not follows rule #1 when writing LaTeX packages: Only use internal code of dead (=unmaintained) LaTeX package. Otherwise contact the package author and figure out a proper interface.

Comment: ...this shows one of the biggest problems with LaTeX: There is no community of "LaTeX package authors", everyone is just writing dirty patches and nobody is talking with affected package authors, there is no quality control at all, the package interfaces in LaTeX have not seen any improvements in decades etc.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the KOMA-Script class `scrartcl`. So you can use its  features to format the captions as desired:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% <- added
\usepackage{bidi}

\KOMAoptions{captions=tableabove}% <- to get the correct spacing between caption and table
\addtokomafont{caption}{\normalfont\small}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{\quad}

\title{A Test}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is a paragraph.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}
\caption{An image}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A simple table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
A cell & and another one \\
and a third & and a fourth \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{A long table}\\
\toprule
A cell & and another one \\
and a third & and a fourth \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the oder of packages:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[xetex,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelfont=bf,font={small,rm},labelsep=quad]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bidi}


\title{A Test}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is a paragraph.

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A simple table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
A cell & and another one \\
and a third & and a fourth \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{A long table}\\
\toprule
A cell & and another one \\
and a third & and a fourth \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]